# Rails set scope based on count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have a Rails scope based on a count of zero.

I have a model = client.  It `has_many :locations`

This didn't work:

```
scope :nolocations, where(:locations.count == 0)
```

What would?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `belongs_to :client, :counter_cache => true`

```
  scope :nolocations, where(locations_count: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 scope :nolocations, ->  { where("locations.count == ?" 0)}
```

If it doesn't work, see on [guides.rubyonrails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)